# Is V 2.79 available for Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, versions

Version 2.82a fails to render animation. I would like to go back to version 2.79 which worked. Is V 2.79 Ubuntu still available?
Where can I find a download for 2.79?

Comment: how to remove v2.83a from Linux64? Also how to manage these tags that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

All previous Blender releases are can be downloaded [here](https://download.blender.org/release/). [Blender 2.79](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) was released for Linux, Windows and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Check Channel switcher on top right corner of Ubuntu Software Center to select version, that you prefer:

[image]

Note, that you can download any version from blender's archives: https://download.blender.org/release/ as Robert suggested, but in this case you should launch blender from downloaded archive.